# Strings with diferent names in "The C Programming Language" book

Tags: c, string, function, integer

In the first chapter of the book there is this example of a code that reads a set of text lines and prints the longest.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000    /* maximum input line size */
 int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);
 /* print longest input line */
main()
{
    int len;            /* current line length */
    int max;            /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE];     /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here */
 max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0)    /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}
 /* getline:  read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;
 for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!=′\n′; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == ′\n′) {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = ′\0′;
    return i;
}
 /* copy:  copy ′from′ into ′to′; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;
 i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != ′\0′)
        ++i;
}
```

In the body of the main function, the author declares `(line,maxline)` as arguments. But later in the getline funcion itself the arguments are `(char s[],int lim)`, which matches so far as data type(the first being a string e the second a int), but they don’t have the same name. Does this mean that it only changes the name of the strings for the reader to understand it easier ? The data which is stored  in the `s` string goes to the `line`  string ?
The same happens for the copy function, the writer calls `(longest, line)` in the body of main, which are both strings with allocated memory in the beginning of the program, and in the void functions itself, the arguments change names to `to[],from[]`. It's really confusing to me. Is he making another array and transporting data, or just referencing these arrays with diferent names to make the code easier to read?
I'm very new to programming/computer science, so sory if my question is dumb or confusing.

Comment: The names in the forward declarations don't really do anything, other than serve as a sort of local documentation as to what the arguments are.  You can omit the argument names entirely in the forward declarations, e.g. `int getline(char [], int);`.

Comment: The arguments in the prototype are just placeholders and only the types matter, but it is good practice to use the same names in the prototype as in the actual function definition; they clearly did not do that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `int getline(char line[], int maxline);`, the parameter names are just placeholders. They have no effect. If they are present, it is generally good programming practice to use the same names as in the later definition of the function.

Inside the `main` routine, where it has `getline(line, MAXLINE)`, this is a function call. It says to pass the value of `line` and the value of `MAXLINE` as arguments to the function. This is a little complicated because `line` is an array, and we cannot use the value of an array in C. Instead, the compiler automatically replaces the array with a pointer to its first element. So this pointer is passed to `getline`.

The definition of `getline` starts with `int getline(char s[], int lim)`. This says:

- Whenever `getline` is called, create a new variable named `s` and initialize it to the value passed for the first argument.
- The complication about arrays has effects here too. Although the parameter `s` is declared as an array, the compiler automatically adjusts this to be a pointer, as if it said `char *s`.
- Also create a new variable named `lim` and initialize it to the value passed for the second argument.

Inside the function, `s` and `lim` can be used, and they will have these initial values. If the function changes `s` or `lim`, this will not affect the caller (the code in `main`) at all. Whatever was used as arguments for the call is not tied to the parameters. The parameters are copies of the passed values.

However, since `s` points to memory that the caller has, whenever the function changes anything `s` points to, that will change the memory the caller is using. So, when `getline` returns to `main`, there will be changes in the `line` array.